# Python - ValueError: Too many values to unpack

Tags: python

I have a very simple code where I want to loop through two lists at the same time. However, this gives me a ValueError: too many values to unpack.

```
def testing_something():
    list1 = [1,2,3,4,45]
    list2 = [1,4,4]
    return list1, list2

for q,z in testing_something():
    print (q,z)
```

The output of testing_something() is ([1, 2, 3, 4, 45], [1, 4, 4]), so I can imagine to be able to loop simultaneously through this output, with q in my case being [1, 2, 3, 4, 45] and z being [1,4,4]. Why does this raise a ValueError?

Comment: Use `itertools.zip_longest` Ex: `for i, v in itertools.zip_longest(list1, list2)`

Comment: I suggest to change the logic of the code or use two loops which iterate over lists

Answer (score 1):

you can't use a single for to iterate over two lists at the same time. You should use zip function

```
def testing_something():
    list1 = [1,2,3,4,45]
    list2 = [1,4,4]
    return list1, list2

for q,z in zip(testing_something()):
    print(q)
    print(z)
```

Note that zip will iterate until the lists have elements: if it finishes iterating over one, it **will stop** iterating. This is solved with **itertools.zip_longest**, which would output None in correspondence of the out-of-bound index: should you want to use it, you have to import the itertools module

Comment: I copied your code made both list1 and list2 equal in length, just for testing purposes and to not use the itertools module. But I still receive an error, this one being ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack. How is this possible?

Comment: You're right: hat's because the function is returning a tuple, which doesn't get "packed out" with zip and you won't get a chance to have the element in the two variables that you declare. Are you forced to do like that in your code? A way to get out of this would be to assing the result of the function to a variable (say, X) and then write zip(X[0],X[1])

Answer (score 1):

If you want `q=[1, 2, 3, 4, 45]` and `z=[1,4,4]` in the first (and only) iteration of the for loop, you should `return [[list1, list2]]`.

However, if you plan to only have one pair of lists returned, you can skip the for loop altogether (and keep the code you posted in the question):

```
q, z = testing_something()
print(q, z)
```

Comment: This will now give me the ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: @Lansing forgot to mention you only need the modification I suggested with the for loop

Answer (score -2):

you can't iterate over single variable as your doing in your for loop,this is the easy way to q,z as your lists.

```
def testing_something():
    list1 = [1,2,3,4,45]
    list2 = [1,4,4]
    return list1, list2

q,z=testing_something()
print q
print z
```

Comment: Yes, this works. But is there no way to loop through two lists at same time as I am trying to achieve? I think I have seen this done more often.